# What are the sharingd and sharedfilelistd processes?

Tags: mac, macos, services

What are the sharingd and sharedfilelistd and why are they running?

[image]

I'm on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a nutshell, **sharedfileslistd** is an XPC helper agent that provides *SharedFilesLists* private API in CoreServices that gets called by, for instance, by LaunchServices APIs and works with so-called *SharedFilesLists* - special property lists that contain NSURL BookmarkData entries. These are used for recent documents/servers/hosts that you see in Apple->Recent Items menu, Favourites/iCloud items/Bonjour hosts that appear in the Finder sidebar, Recent Documents in applications' Save/Open dialogs) and such.

**sharingd** is sharing daemon that enables AirDrop, Handoff, Instant Hotspot, Shared Computers, and Remote Disc in the Finder.

Comment: Do you know how this relates to Photos.app? I see in Security & Privacy that sharedfileslistd is allowed access to Photos. In my tired head the best I can think of is it allows for e.g. AirDrop or something along those lines.

Comment: @Pryftan: I guess that's in order to allow other apps to access pictures by URL (think of an image picker that lets you browse photos navigating by album/date/face/younameit in a UI that is a standard "Open File" pane)

Comment: I am trying to remember the context of the question and how or why I encountered this too. I don't honestly recall; I've just had too much going on and I probably resolved my issue (if it was an issue at all!). I think though that based on what little I can think of/remember you're probably right though I would think more for importing/exporting photos (and as I said AirDrop too) rather than URL (unless maybe you refer to URI).

Comment: For me it's just surprising to see something this cryptic in the Apple Security & Privacy menus by default - I would have thought it would be hidden from the Privacy view, or somehow made to look nicer/more understandable for end users. Anyway this answer helped me figure out it's normal and nothing to worry about.